# Install VC++ Redistributables for Visual Studio 2015-2022 with MSI setup

Tags: windows-installer, vcredist, visual-c++-2022

I have a Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 VC++ application that is distributed as MSI file and installs the VC++ redistributable as merge modules. It’s a server application that is always installed for all users and it works.

Now, I found out that these merge modules are deprecated according to [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=msvc-170](https://stackoverflow.com) so that am looking for a recommended option.

I already tries to change my MSI setup (using WIX v3) to install the redistributable by running vc_redist.x86.exe as custom action. The problem is that it fails with error 1618 (Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this install.) like mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072307/how-to-install-vc-redistributables-in-advanced-installer](https://stackoverflow.com).

I do not want to use one the following alternative options:

- Run the custom action after 'Finish Execution'. Reason: VC++ runtime is required earlier.
- Link the VC++ runtime statically. Reason: It is not updated by Windows Update.
- Install VC++ runtime in the application directory. Reason: It is not updated by Windows Update.
- Use a .exe bootstrapper. Reason: It breaks compatibility with the consumer of my product.

Is there a suggested solution for installing the VC++ redistributable as prerequisite with an MSI setup?